# @angular/forms/FormsModule missing

Tags: angular

I am trying to import the FormsModule from @angular/forms@0.3.0 inside Angular 2 RC5. Should be simple right?

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

However this is not part of the @angular/forms library which I installed using

```
npm install @angular/forms
```

Some have suggested using:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

However this doesn't work either.

I've looked into the forms package and it appears that it's in the form_providers typing file (form_providers.d.ts) and it does mention FormsModule. In the forms.js it mentiones __export(require('./form_providers')); so this means it should be available right?

Any ideas how I fix this problem?

Many thanks

JT

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule}   from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {MeteorModule} from 'angular2-meteor';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, MeteorModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,[ disableDeprecatedForms(),provideForms()]));
```

**Package.json** (that is being used by "npm install")

```
{
  "name": "angular2-meteor-base",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha",
    "test:ci": "meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "latest",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-meteor": "latest",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "latest",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "latest",
    "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "latest",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: 'Hello World'
})

export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using rc.5?

Comment: yes, i'm using RC5

Comment: are you adding FormsModule as as an import in you module component? i.e import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; and... below in the @ngModule like so imports: [BrowserModule, Routing, FormsModule, HttpModule],

Comment: Have you removed and re-installed the forms package?  Otherwise, can you dig into the forms directory (node_modules/@angular/forms/src) and look at the form_providers typing file (form_providers.d.ts) and make sure it mentions FormsModule...if it does, then the package has everything you need, something else wonky is happening

Comment: if I am not being clear enough then please post you module.ts component

Comment: the imports are being done correctly AFAIK. Yes, it's in the form_providers typing file (form_providers.d.ts) and it does mention FormsModule. In the forms.js it mentiones __export(require('./form_providers')); so this means it should be available right?

Comment: Further assistance with this will require some more code to be posted. could you post your app module that references the import please.

Comment: Thanks @Bean0341. I've added the code above.

Comment: Is it just failing to compile/transpile it or are you getting some other error?

Comment: I would change, in package.json, @angular/forms for read "0.3.0" rather than "latest", If that doesnt work... when you ran "npm install @angular/forms" did you get any warnings?

Comment: OK, that's fixed somehow. I've removed the node_module directory (again) and reinstalled the modules. Uuurrgghh..... Thanks very much for all your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and had to update my package.json to specify the version of forms to the following:

```
"@angular/forms": "^0.3.0",
```

After that running an npm update.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you added `FormsModule` to the app module or module you are working on and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it just using the following steps:

- write **import {} from '@angular/forms';**
- after that, write **FormsModule** in the **{}**
- finally write **FormsModule** in the **imports**

It worked.

Comment: A pity that you didn't post a code sample :-(